# Definite article before news

Tags: grammar, articles

> *Let's learn English with **the** news*

In the above sentence is the definite article "the" referring to a particular news?

The above sentence is the heading of a YouTube video for English learners

Comment: No, it's referring to news generically. Newscasts.

Comment: You should always give the context of a sentence you are asking about. My guess is that this refers to 'the news' in the sense 'a regular TV or radio news bulletin' and not 'a particular _item of_ news'.

Comment: What @KateBunting said. Or in the slightly more general sense of ‘significant recent events,’ whether as described in accounts from broadcast, digital, or print media, or as introduced in the YouTube video itself.

Answer (score 2):

1. "News" in English is used in a "non-count" way; that is, there's no such thing as "a news." We might say "a piece of news" or "a news article." So, without any further context, the snippet quoted is definitely not referring to a particular piece of reporting or a particular current event.
2. When the definite article is included, this often means a large, generic body of reporting on current events. See definition 2A [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/news), "material reported in a newspaper or news periodical or on a newscast." We might say things like "I'm tired of this nature show, let's watch the news," or "When I wake up I read the news." It can mean a specific news-reporting show, like "the news is on at 11," or the entire press industry, like "Brad Pitt has been in the news a lot recently."

This is almost certainly the usage meant here. I'll add, you *could* use "the" with news and still mean a specific piece of information... if the context made that clear. Like "I came as soon as I heard *the news that you were sick*." See definition 1 from the link above.